# Identifying Period Type

Tags: theory, analysis, cadence, phrase

I've attached a music excerpt that's been stumping me. Is the attached passage a parallel period or a contrasting period? The rhythmic repetition makes it seem parallel, but the chord progression and melody seem contrasting.

[image: Two rhythmically similar but harmonically different phrases]

Comment: Did you really attach a _music expert_ or did you in fact attach a _music excerpt_?

Comment: TBH, attaching a music expert would be a bit redundant.

Comment: Please add the title and composer of the piece in case someone else is studying it, too.

Answer (score 1):

#### TL;DR

With allowance for the interpretive aspect of music analysis ...

I would label this a **parallel** period.

#### The ambiguity

The problem, of course, lies in the ambiguity in the definitions of parallel and contrasting periods. For example:

> In a parallel period, the melodies in both phrases begin similarly. In a contrasting period, the phrases begin differently. ([Source](https://musictheory.pugetsound.edu/mt21c/PeriodForm.html): Music Theory for the 21st-Century Classroom by Robert Hutchinson, "13.3.4 Parallel and Contrasting Periods")

This is easy when the parallel phrases begin *identically*, which is often the case. However, the definition doesn't explain *how similar* or *how contrasting*. Thus, **the answer depends on how heavily one weighs the parallel aspects of the phrase against the contrasting ones.**

#### Interpretation

Here's my own informal definition.

> In a parallel period, the consequent phrase begin such that the listener is likely to recall or associate it with the antecedent. In a contrasting period, the consequent phrase is intended to present a wholly new idea.

For my own purposes, at least, this way of looking at it makes the phrase in question parallel. Even with the harmonic contrast, the rhythm is enough to bring the listener clearly back to the antecedent phrase, which I interpret as the composer's intent. I would expect a contrasting phrase to be "more contrasting" than this one.

#### Opposing view

My own definition could be used to make the opposite point. Given the harmonic change, perhaps the composer's intent is to highlight the contrast between the two phrases — specifically by adding just enough parallelism to reference the antecedent phrase, but not enough to make the phrases "genuinely" parallel.

This again comes back to the idea that the label depends on the interpreter's prioritization of the parallel aspects versus the contrasting ones. I give more weight to the parallel in this particular case (though reserve the right to analyze another seemingly similar phrase differently). But an interpreter giving more weight to the contrast wouldn't be wrong.

... And thus begins many a debate among music theorists.

#### The ultimate test

When in doubt, listen to the passage. This is the essential arbiter of music theory questions: how do you, the theorist, hear the passage. If the antecedent phrase recalls for you the consequent, it's parallel; if the antecedent phrase sounds like it's own entity, then it's contrasting.

Comment: This answer is very good. I wonder if it would help to suggest that form is often better heard with the ear rather than seen on the page. The asker might listen to a performance of the piece and ask themselves if they *hear* parallelism or not.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Thanks, and thanks for the suggestion. Added.